# Inability to Import Certain .NET Classes

Tags: .net, ironpython, spotfire

I am attempting to use some classes within the `System.Threading.Tasks` .NET namespace within Spotfire v7.6 Analyst to utilize the Parallel class for the `Parallel.ForEach` method. I unfortunately cannot import this class within Spotfire, yet within the IronPython interpreter I can (as in the console run outside of Spotfire); this issue is not just limited to this class within the namespace, as some others, which I cannot currently recall, are having the same issue, too. Is this issue particular to me or is this an intended exclusion for Spotfire?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I am getting an import error: `ImportError: Cannot import name Parallel`